# Шаблонная страница в WP с изменением расположения блоков

Tags: html, wordpress, cms

Помогите пожалуйста. Есть меню, в меню есть очень много одинаковых страниц, только меняется расположение блоков на странице и текст. Иногда на странице больше блоков, иногда меньше (одинаковых блоков). Еще вся сложность в том, что иногда в одном из блоков бывает 6 пунктов, иногда 12, иногда 3 (т.е. всегда разное количество). Внизу пример такого блока. Подскажите как такую шаблонную страницу можно реализовать, как блоки вставлять в разные части страницы. Любой помощи буду очень рад. Будь это просто мысли, или же функции php с объяснением или ссылка на документацию, все будет очень полезно.

```html
<div class="container__inner service__price">
    <h2 class="h2 service__price__title">Что входит в структуру брендбука</h2>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="service__price__inner">
            <div class="service__price__inner__left">
                <p class="p__light service__price__text">Структура </p>

                <div class="service__stages__inner__content">
                    <div class="service__stages__text__img">
                        <p class="service__stages__text__img__logo">01</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p__light service__stages__text__plus">Маркетинговая </p>
                </div>

                <div class="service__stages__inner__content">
                    <div class="service__stages__text__img">
                        <p class="service__stages__text__img__logo">02</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p__light service__stages__text__plus">Преимущества </p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="service__stages__inner__content">
                    <div class="service__stages__text__img">
                        <p class="service__stages__text__img__logo">03</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p__light service__stages__text__plus">Презентация </p>
                </div>    

                
            </div>
            <div class="service__price__inner__right">    
                
                
                
                <div class="service__stages__inner__content">
                    <div class="service__stages__text__img">
                        <p class="service__stages__text__img__logo">04</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p__light service__stages__text__plus">Индивидуальные </p>
                </div>    
              
                <div class="service__stages__inner__content">
                    <div class="service__stages__text__img">
                        <p class="service__stages__text__img__logo">05</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p__light service__stages__text__plus">Фирменные </p>
                </div>    
              
                <div class="service__stages__inner__content">
                    <div class="service__stages__text__img">
                        <p class="service__stages__text__img__logo">06</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p__light service__stages__text__plus">Визуальная </p>
                </div>    
              
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /container -->
</div><!-- /service__price -->
```

Comment: Ну например если Вы используете в своей теме Gutenberg, то при помощи ACF можно добавить свои Gutenberg блоки. Подробнее можете почитать [здесь](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/), так же [пример](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/building-a-custom-slider-block-in-30-minutes-with-acf/) добавления своего блока.

Comment: Не использую Gutenberg

Comment: Что используете? Classic Editor?

Comment: Да, его, а про gutenberg слышу первый раз, так как я мало знаком с WP

Comment: Ну в таком случае можно использовать [ACF Flexible Content](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/), опять же если я Вас верно понял. Это даст Вам возможность менять порядок расположения различных блоков.